# UIButton animated re-positioning does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, uiviewanimation

I'm having an issue with animating a UIButton into a new position.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:kFadeAnimationInterval
                 animations:^{
                     button.frame = newFrame;
                 }];
```

Executing the code does not have any effect on the button's position.
Not sure if it's related, but the Interface is laid out in a NIB file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: in which method are you calling this code? did you check that button isn't nil?

Comment: @suprandr I'm calling it in a custom method residing in a view controller after inserting some subviews.

Comment: Is the button connected by an outlet (if it is resident in a xib)?

Comment: Make sure that you doing it in main thread

Comment: @Andrea Yes, I have an IBOutlet referencing the button.

Comment: What is the superview of the button ?

Comment: @KIDdAe the superview is a UIView that is loaded from a NIB file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using AutoLayout to position the button? That might be the causing issues with changing the position in your animation.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add some information? Try to breakpoint the app before the animation call, and inside the completion blocks. Print the current frame/pointer info of the buttom, etc. Also, does the code work if you simply change the frame without the animation?